# On AArch64, how does SCTLR_EL1.SPAN=0 work when a translation fault occurs while PSTATE.PAN=1?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm64, xnu

For example, the XNU kernel has the `copyin()`/`copyout()` functions to copy data from user-space to kernel-space and vice versa. Since these functions need to access user-space, they disable PAN by setting `PSTATE.PAN` to `0`. However, if `SCTLR_EL1.SPAN` is set to `0`, the specification says that "PSTATE.PAN is set to 1 on taking an exception to EL1".

First, let's say that a translation fault occurs during the copy operation while PAN is enabled (either on a user address or a kernel address). Then, an exception would be taken to EL1. Note that we were already running in EL1, so I'm not 100% sure that this counts as taking an exception "to EL1". I'll assume that it does, but please correct me if I'm wrong. In that case, because `SCTLR_EL1.SPAN` is set to `0`, PAN is re-enabled automatically before the fault handler is executed.

Next, let's say that the fault handler succeeds (i.e. it finds the page and inserts it in the page tables), then what happens when the exception returns? I don't see any mention in the specification that PAN should be re-disabled automatically when the exception returns. However, if PAN stays enabled, then the next user-space access will trigger another exception, which should cause a kernel panic because the kernel is accessing a user address while PAN is enabled.

What am I getting wrong? I'm more familiar with XNU, but the same question probably applies to the Linux kernel with `copy_from_user()`/`copy_to_user()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Arm® Architecture Reference Manual for A-profile architecture](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest/), section D8.4.1 *"Effect of PSTATE on access permission"*:

> When taking an exception from an EL in AArch64 state to an `ELx`, `PSTATE.PAN` is saved to and restored from `SPSR_ELx.PAN`.

And if we take a look at `SPSR_EL1.PAN` in section C5.2.18 we can read:

> **When `FEAT_PAN` is implemented**:
>
> Privileged Access Never. Set to the value of `PSTATE.PAN` on taking an exception to EL1, and copied to `PSTATE.PAN` on executing an exception return operation in EL1.

So this seems like an easy hardware-assisted way to solve the problem. No magic software workarounds needed.

Comment: Thanks for this fantastic answer! I didn't know about SPSR_ELx.PAN... I'll have to look for other PPL bypass ideas!